# HTTP 406 downloading a file with rest call

Tags: java, spring, rest

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/032-return-file-from-spring-rest-webservice/) to implement rest API with Spring Boot for downloading files (xml format).

My controller class is as follows:

```
@RestController
public class RistoreController {
    @Autowired
    private RistoreService ristoreService;

    @RequestMapping( 
            value = "/ristore/foundation/{trf}", 
            method = RequestMethod.GET, 
            produces = "application/xml")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStream> getXMLById(@PathVariable("trf") String trf) throws IOException {
        InputStream inputStream = ristoreService.findByTRF(trf);
        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(inputStream);
    }
}
```

I have service interface `RistoreService` autowired in the controller and Bean class for that service looks like this:

```
@Service
public class RistoreServiceBean implements RistoreService {
    public InputStream findByTRF(String trf) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "/Users/djiao/Box Sync/Work/Projects/RIStore/foundation/foundation_new/" + trf + ".xml";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    }
}
```

I tested the application using the following curl command:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" http://localhost:8080/ristore/foundation/TRF133672_1455294493597
```

However, I got 406 error, "Not Acceptable". Something wrong with the file format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the definition of the controller that way

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/ristore/foundation/{trf}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/xml")
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadXMLFile(@PathVariable("trf") String trf)
            throws IOException {

        // Optinal headers configuration 

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

        headers.add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        headers.add("Expires", "0");


        // get the inputStream

    InputStream xmlFileInputStream = ristoreService.findByTRF(trf);



        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(xmlFileInputStream));
    }
```

Then your service class would be :

```
 @Service
public class RistoreServiceBean implements RistoreService {
    public InputStream findByTRF(String trf) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "/Users/djiao/Box Sync/Work/Projects/RIStore/foundation/foundation_new/" + trf + ".xml";
        File file = new File(filePath);
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    }
}
```

> 406 Not Acceptable
>   The resource identified by the request is only capable of generating response entities which have content characteristics not acceptable according to the accept headers sent in the request.

That means that the inputstream you return must be considered as a resource as soon as you have a REST controller.

Comment: This works. I added `@PathVariable("trf") String trf` as argument for method `downloadXMLFile`. I don't think `InputStream` has `contentLength()` method if you meant `xmlFileInputStream` by `xmlFile`.

Comment: I edited the answer to add the @pathVariable that i forgot. But the thing here was mainly because of the ResourceInputStream for the reasons i explained in the answer. For the file length you are right.

In my case i would return a file from the service then convert the file in the controller. In this case you can get the file length. Don't forget to validate the answer please.

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines in your code contradict each other:

```
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/octet-stream"))
```

and

```
        produces = "application/xml")
```

Comment: Changed it to `contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/xml"))` and still getting the same error.

Comment: There is no contradiction actually. It renturns the content as a octet stream which after gathering will be reassembled as body for an XML file ( application/xml)